# SELECT query for non latin string works through phpMyAdmin but not on the search form

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

With my code below I convert XML to mySQL and after that I search (from a form) and it returns me the id of the entry that the term was found in.

Through phpmyAdmin

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('ηλιακές')
```

I get the correct return.

Through the script I also get the correct results.

But when I go through the search form textbox, I did not get any. Why is that?
I have to say that the DB is **utf8_general_ci**

Thank you.

**search page**

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
Term: <input type="text" name="term" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe setting an header in the result page

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;?>
```

will help